# Autohotkey in Visual Studio Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2013, autohotkey

I have a problem to use Autohotkey to open - File menu (inside of Visual Studio) and  select "Recent projects & solutions". It works fine inside of notepad with this code:

```
^+r::
WinMenuSelectItem, Untitled - Notepad, , File, Open
Return
```

But it does not work inside VS:

```
WinMenuSelectItem, ahk_class Svitlana-PC • Sniffsters (Debug|Any CPU) - Microsoft Visual Studio, , File, Open
```

Probably because I cannot specify a wintitle correctly - I tried many variants from WinSpy, but I did not succeed.

Can anybody give me an advice or direction?

Thank you for reading.
Best,
Svitlana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try activating the window (if that doesn't work, make the mouse click on the title bar of the window).

Then use `!f` to open the file menu and navigate the menu by sending letter keys.  Microsoft programs are always tricky to work with.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got to open a file menu :-). !f works, however, Recent project and solutions do not have a symbol with undescore, I can count, but it order is changing. How would you treat this problem, BGM?

However, you already saved my sanity - THANK YOU!

Comment: You are welcome.  Let me think of something and I'll mention it here if I come up with something.

Comment: Hmmm... there could be several solutions to achive your goal, but we can't really go through it here in comments...  If you ask another question about it, ping me.